# How do I prove that a term is divisible by another term by using induction?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

I need to prove that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ is divisble by $(n+1)$, for all natural numbers $n$.
I ofcourse start with the base case $n = 1$ and formulate the induction hypothesis that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!} = m(n + 1)$ for some integer $m$. 
Then I perform the induction step: $\frac{(2n + 2)!}{(n + 1)!(n + 1)!} = l(n + 2)$ 
Then I expand the expression to $\frac{(2n + 2)(2n + 1)(2n)!}{(n + 1)(n + 1)(n!)(n!)} = l(n + 2)$ and then substitute 
$\frac{(2n + 2)(2n + 1)(n + 1)m}{(n + 1)(n + 1)} = l(n + 2)$. I further simplify and arrive at $2m(2n + 1) = l(n + 2)$ and this is where I am stuck. I don't know what to do next or if I started wrong. Any help would be appreciated. (And excuse me if I miss used some terms, I am not a native English speaker.)

Comment: Are you required to prove this by induction or can you use any method that works?

Comment: @RobertShore I can prove it however I want, but I initially thought that i would be easier to prove it by induction. If you have another way to prove this I would appreciate it too.

Comment: Induction doesn't work well here - it is rate we can use that $n+1$ divides one number to prove $n+2$ divides another number.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!(n-1)!}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}.$$

Comment: More generally, $$\binom mn=\binom m{n+1}\cdot \frac{n+1}{m-n}$$ so $\binom mn$ is divisible by $n+1$ when $\gcd(n+1,m+1)=1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am not sure how I can use your hint to show that the term is divisible by $n + 1$. Could you please elaborate on it a bit more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove using properties of divisors and or induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895823/prove-using-properties-of-divisors-and-or-induction) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%2B1%5Cmid%5Cbinom%7B2n%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1). Note that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=\binom{2n}{n}$. Also, FYI, another basic duplicate question is [Prove $n{2n\choose n}=(n+1){2n\choose n-1}$ and $(n+1)|{2n\choose n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3110392).

Comment: @JohnOmielan yep, that answers my question. I also saw that it equaled ${2n\choose n}$ but I haven't considered going that route. Thanks!

Comment: @Ams1901 If you don't recognize binomials, then my hint isn't much use. If you do recognize binomials, you should be able to figure it out.  Do you know why $(2n)!/n!^2$ is an integer?